# Android - ActionSherlock navigation bar buttons don't invoke corresponding actions

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, android-actionbar

I have been able to place the sharing widget as well as the ListNavigation on my actionbar.  But when I click them, the share button does not give me options to share, and the ListNavigation does not take me to the list item that I chose.

Here is the code I have to set this up:

```
public class MainActivity extends SherlockActivity implements ActionBar.OnNavigationListener
{
    Dialog dialog;

    private TextView mSelected;
    private String[] mLocations;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        setTheme(R.style.Theme_Sherlock_Light);

        //setContentView(R.layout.list_navigation);
        mSelected = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.text);

        mLocations = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.locations);


        Context context = getSupportActionBar().getThemedContext();
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> list = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
                context, R.array.locations, R.layout.sherlock_spinner_item);
        list.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.sherlock_spinner_dropdown_item);

        getSupportActionBar().setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_LIST);
        getSupportActionBar().setListNavigationCallbacks(list, this);        

and here is my menu inflater and other relevant methods:

    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
    {       
        MenuInflater inflater = getSupportMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu);
        return true;
    }

    private Intent createShareIntent() 
    {   
        Intent shareIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        shareIntent.setType("text/plain"); //shareIntent.setType("image/*");

        shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,"Mobile apps to plan and start your busienss, covering business ideas, business planning, marketing and fundraising.");
        shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Check out http://www.myurl.com");

        return shareIntent;
    }
```

And this method never gets called when I select one of the menu items:

```
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(int itemPosition, long itemId) 
{        
    if ( itemPosition == 0 )
    {
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
        MainActivity.this.startActivity(myIntent);          
    }
    else
    if ( itemPosition == 1 )
    {
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, LearnActivity.class);
        MainActivity.this.startActivity(myIntent);          
    }        
    else
    if ( itemPosition == 2 )
    {
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ServicesActivity.class);
        MainActivity.this.startActivity(myIntent);          
    }        
    else
    if ( itemPosition == 3 )
    {
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, GiveBackActivity.class);
        MainActivity.this.startActivity(myIntent);
    }                

    return true;
}
```

And here is my main_menu.xml

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">  

<item android:id="@+id/menu_item_share"         
android:showAsAction="ifRoom"         
android:title="Share"         
android:actionProviderClass="android.widget.ActionProvider" />  

<item
android:id="@+id/menuSort"
android:showAsAction="ifRoom"
android:actionLayout="@layout/action_sort"  />

</menu>
```

Would anyone know why neither the sharing widget nor the ListNavigation calls its corresponding method when selected?

I also get these two errors/warnings when booting the simulator:

```
[2013-06-27 08:43:57 - actionbarsherlock] 'default' is not a best match for any device/locale combination.
[2013-06-27 08:43:57 - actionbarsherlock] Displaying it with ', , Locale Language ___Region __, sw320dp, w320dp, h533dp, Normal Screen, Long screen aspect ratio, Portrait Orientation, Normal, Day time, High Density, Finger-based touchscreen, Soft keyboard, No keyboard, Hidden navigation, Trackball navigation, Screen resolution 800x480, API Level 15' which is compatible, but will actually be displayed with another more specific version of the layout.
```

And here is the screenshot of how the screen elements on the app get grayed out:

[image]

And if I put a debug statement in the code, it seems that the onNavigationItemSelected() method keeps getting called in a loop like 100 times per minute or so.

Thanks!
- Alex

Answer (score 1):

It appears that you have commented out the line that actually connects the navigation listener:

```
// getSupportActionBar().setListNavigationCallbacks(list, this);
```

I don't see `onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem)`, which is what's called when the Action Bar buttons are pressed.

Also, not sure if you forgot the `@Override` annotation on `onNavigationItemSelected` and `onCreateOptionsMenu`, but it's not shown.

Comment: the reason I commented that line out is it causes strange app behavior. When that line gets put back in, the whole screen gets overlayed with gray. So the app appears all gray. Would you know why that happens?

Comment: And yes, my @averrides are there - I just didn't copy them.

Comment: And I thought that the onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem) is not needed because the onNavigationItemSelected() method can tell what ListNavigation item was selected. Or am I wrong about that somehow?

Comment: @Genadinik There is no callback if `setListNavigationCallbacks` is not set. Your adapter is not "hooked into" anything. `onNavigationItemSelected` is only called from the Spinner. You must use `onOptionsItemSelected` for menu items, no matter what.

Comment: On the "app appears all gray" issue, I'd need to see the full code to determine that issue, but it's not something I've ever seen/heard of. Feel free to link to a pastebin and I'll take a look.

Comment: I have a long meeting starting in 10 min. Would you be around later today? And also, if you could, would you be able to paste how the onOptionsItemSelected() method might look like? I could give it a try.  Thank you!!

Comment: I think it's time you read the official documentation. On Menus: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html

Comment: I did take a good look at the documentation. And I added this method onOptionsItemSelected() but it also does not get called. Which part of the code did you need to look at? I pasted quite a bit of it in my initial question.

Comment: Are you using the proper classes for `Menu`, `OnNavigationListener`, etc? Make sure you are importing the ABS/HoloEverywhere classes, and not the regular ones.